# How to drop a variable from the $_GET in php

Tags: php

I have a side nav link area for certain pages and it's built like so:

On the top of the side vertical nav i'm echoing the trainers first and last name. Below that is a pages array for each page path and it's item name on the side menu.

```
echo "$trainer->last, $trainer->first</div>";
            $pages = array('edit'=>'Info','comment/lookup'=>'Comments','images/lookup'=>'Images','trainer_group_edit/lookup'=>'Groups'); 
            echo matry::aliased_links($pages);
```

Paths are like this when clicked on different items:

```
edit&trainer_id=19584

comment/lookup&trainer_id=19584

/images/lookup&trainer_id=19584
```

Groups is on the end of the array the last menu item but when it's clicked I would like to drop the trainer_id variable in the get and maybe add a different variable, at this point it would be great if i could just drop it altogether.

Could i use the strtok function — Tokenize string??

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

here is the function for:
matry::aliased_links

```
public static function aliased_links($pages = array(), $qs = array(), $class = 'vertical_nav', $base = 0)
    {
    $s = "<ul class='$class'>";
    foreach ($pages as $k=>$v)
        {
        $dir = explode("/", $k);
        $s .= "<li"; if (in_array(self::$me, $dir)) { $s .= " class='selected'"; }
        $s .= "><a class='big' href='";
        $s .= $base ? self::base_to($k, $qs) : self::here_to($k, $qs);
        $s .= "'>$v</a></li>";
        }
    return $s . '</ul>';
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you just need something like `unset($_GET['not_needed']);`?

Comment: I thought that might work as well but i didn't try it nor have i ever used it, i'll give it a go. Thank you.

Comment: if you had two ideas, why not try them before asking on here? i'm genuinely curious.

Comment: I tried a few iterations but i believe my syntax is wrong. I'll post what i have.

Comment: Is what you're trying to say that you want to generate a link to `trainer_group_edit/lookup` without adding the `trainer_id` parameter? Presumably that parameter is automatically added in your `matry::aliased_links` function, so some change will be needed there, but you haven't shown us that function.

Comment: i updated my edits for aliased_links function. Thanks for keeping up with this thread.

Answer (score 4):

You should use [unset](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php) function. I think it is self explanatory.

```
 unset($_GET['trainer_id']); //Drops the key 'trainer_id' inside $_GET.

 unset($_GET); //Drops the value of the entire $_GET variable.
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: How to I add that into my array?

Comment: I'm not sure how that would be inserted into my array because i'm throwing a syntax error.      $pages = array('edit'=>'Info','comment/lookup'=>'Comments','images/lookup'=>'Images','trainer_group_edit/lookup'unset($_GET['trainer_id'])'=>'Groups');

Comment: Still now working for me, if you could maybe help me figure this last part out, please.

Comment: @HeadWay, you can't unset there! Try to put that before _$pages_.

Comment: @HeadWay. Maybe like this: unset($_GET['trainer_id']); $pages = array('edit'=>'Info','comment/lookup'=>'Comments','images/lookup'=>'Images','tra‌​iner_group_edit/lookup'=>'Groups');

Comment: that didn't quite work but i understand how to use unset way better now. Thank you.